# method called two times on one click

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF on the front and hibernate on back end in my application. The problem is that there is a method it saves the record in database(Oracle 11g), it calls from the user interface 'on click' , but seems like it run two times instead of one, on a single click. Although not every time.

I am sharing a code of that method here :

```
MedOpd med = new MedOpd();

med.setStaff(staff);
med.setNotes(this.notes);   
med.setOpdDate(ICMSUtils.getCurrentDateSQL());
med.setMedPatient(medPat);

HashMap dataMap = new HashMap();
HashMap dataMap2 = new HashMap();
dataMap.put(APP_OBJECT.MED, med);

dataMap2 = handleDoctorProcessorLocal.processMedicineProcessor(
                    dataMap, APP_ACTIONS.SAVE);

String result = dataMap2.get(APP_VARIABLES.RESULT).toString();      
if(result.equals(RESULTS.SUCCESS))
{
mo = (MedOpd) dataMap2.get(APP_OBJECT.MEDOPD);

for (int i = 0; i < opdMedicineList.size(); i++) 
    {
    MedMedicines mom2 = (MedMedicines) opdMedicineList.get(i);
    mom2.setMedOpd(mo);

    mom2.setMiName(mom2.getMedItem().getMiName());
    mom2.setMiCode(mom2.getMedItem().getMiCode());
    mom2.setIssued("P");

    dataMap.put(APP_OBJECT.MEDOPDMEDICINE, mom2);
    dataMap = handleDoctorProcessorLocal.
                          processOpdDoctorProcessor(
                                 dataMap, APP_ACTIONS.SAVE+"MEDMEDICINE");
    }

}
```

as you can see, its a master / detail record which i am saving in database, the code is running fine but some times, the method saves two same records on a single click and their detail will be duplicated also. I would also like to share the Database ID's generated for the same record here :

```
Master Table ID : 1010
Detail Table Records : 
1. DET_ID=2010, MAS_ID=1010
2. DET_ID=2012, MAS_ID=1010
2. DET_ID=2015, MAS_ID=1010

Master Table ID : 1011
Detail Table Records : 
1. DET_ID=2011, MAS_ID=1011
2. DET_ID=2013, MAS_ID=1011
2. DET_ID=2014, MAS_ID=1011
```

Please note that i am not using Threads in my application, but this page is uses by multiple users at a time, there is no static fields or method in this class at all..

Here is the jsp code :

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:20%; margin:10px 50px 10px 80px;">

<ajax:commandButton id="save1" value="Next" action="#{opdManager.saveMedicine2}" reRender="patientPanel" />

</h:panelGrid>
```

well the whole jsp page is very complicated, so i just share the Button code which invokes the method. The "saveMedicine2" method only use once in the whole jsp.

Comment: Add your  user interface code

Comment: Why are you showing the method's code instead of the code of who's invoking that method? Are you implying that when you replace all that method's code by a simple `System.out.println("test")`, that it's then invoked only once? No? Then the whole method's code is irrelevant to the concrete problem.